# Unable to move breadcrumb items to float to the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I am developing an application using Vue.js and Bootstrap. I am developing a breadcrumb in which I want the icons to be displayed to the right and the text "Files" to float to the left.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="conatainer-fluid">
      <ol class="breadcrumb" style="padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem; background-color: transparent">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Files</li>
        <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc"></i></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <hr id="breadcrumb_hr">
```

Despite using pull-right, the breadcrumb icons aren't floating to the right.

The breadcrumb looks like this
[image: Picture]

What wrong am I doing here?

Comment: did you try to add this rule to your style `float:right`?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't work

Comment: and how do you want it to look?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this css, its work

```
.breadcrumb{
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;

}
.breadcrumb-item.active{
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

or use html

```
  <div class="conatainer-fluid">
      <ol class="breadcrumb" style="display:flex; width:100%; padding: 0rem 1rem 0rem; background-color: transparent">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="margin-right:auto">Files</li>
        <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-sort-amount-asc"></i></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-th-large"></i></li>
        <li class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-list-ul"></i></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
```

Comment: Or can use the bootstrap class `mr-auto`. `<li class="breadcrumb-item active mr-auto">Files</li>`.

Answer (score -1):

Perfect! it's really works.Wows
!